# Trying to avoid javascript eval()

Tags: javascript, variables, eval

Let's say I want to add variable interpolation to String like so:

```
String.prototype.interpolate = function() {
    return this.replace(/{(\S+?)}/g, function(match, $1) {return eval($1);});
}
```

If all of my variables are global or local then I could replace `eval($1)` with `this[$1]`. However if I've got something like `var name = {first: 'Joe', last: 'Blogs'};` then `this[$1]` will not work to interpolate `"Hello, {name.first} {name.last}!".interpolate()`. Is there anything I could use in place of `eval()`? If I'm expecting those variables to come from an untrusted source then I really cannot use `eval()`.

Comment: You should use some little templating engine. Read about http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/ it's quite small and tricky :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a pre-existing template engine, I'd suggest making the data to interpolate explicit:

```
String.prototype.interpolate = function(data) {
    return this.replace(/{(\S+?)}/g, function(match, $1) {return data[$1];});
}

console.log( '{a} is better than {b}'.interpolate({'a':'explicit', 'b':'implicit'}) );
```

Comment: @biziclop: That micro-templating stuff is pretty nice but not usable under `'use strict';` conditions since it uses `with`.

Comment: abesto: That certainly works but seems to violate the principle of Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: @ChristopherWeiss: only if the parameter is built in place like this. In a good number of cases it'll be available in a pre-existing object.